# How to select items in JQ based on values in array

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with data like this:

```
{ 
  "data": {
    "all": {
      "members": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "First"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Second"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Third"
        }
      ],
      "live": {
        "online": [
          10,
          14
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use jq to select and show only the JSON values in `data.all.members` that have their `id` in `data.all.live.online` array?

So the output would be something like:

```
{
"members": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "First"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Third"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
jq '.data.all
| .live.online as $online
| {members}
| .members |= map( select(.id | IN($online[]) // null) )
' data.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying : this works when i have entries in `.live.online`, but when `.live.online` is empty i still have members selected. Also if my online number are `100,214`, the members `10,14` are selected but they should'nt. Can you be kind enough to help me tighten the `IN($online[])` thingy ? Thanks in advance ! Also can you point me out some usefull resources / examples / cheatsheets for jq ? [jq Manual (development version)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) already pinned.

Comment: See revision for a more robust version.  See the jq FAQ for guidance: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, so let's say you have it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should be fairly easy to understand:

```
.data.all
| .live.online as $online
| { members: .members | map(select([.id] | inside($online))) }
```

Output:

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "First"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Third"
    }
  ]
}
```

And if you need more flexibility how your ids are matched:

```
.data.all
| .live.online as $online
| { members: .members | map(select(.id as $id | $online | any(. == $id))) }
```

Comment: looks really similar to @peak answer

Comment: @pieplu yes, it is similar. But it provides two solutions. The first one being simpler, the second one allowing more flexibility